# Can node.js do parallel computations

Tags: node.js

I know node.js can do parallel IO, but can it do by itself or via a plugin parallel computations for multicore processors. Like if i want to do large matrix multiplications.

I have on older questions here at stackflow that node is working on such a feature. Anyone knows how far along it is.

Answer (score 3):

The official cluster module is what you are looking for:
http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_cluster